# php dns_get_record ("something.com", DNS_TXT) return false

Tags: php, dns, dns-get-record

I am trying to get spf record to validate sender address but function return false for :

```
$result = dns_get_record('airhelp.com', DNS_ANY);
```

In `mxtoolbox.com` I see that site has multi txt records

[image: mxtoolbox txt lookup]

Please help me, how could I get those spf (txt) records and please advice me why it isn't working for those domains

UPDATE:

I have discovered that problem exist only for those specific domain and if I query from my local ip...is I query from other ip it works just fine...is it possible that dns rejects my request on the basis of my local ip?

Comment: Do not use ANY (or ALL). This certainly does not have the meaning and results you expect them to have, and it is now deprecated so many nameserver may not reply to you at all. You can not retrieve "all" resources records for a name. Please state your problem, why you are attempting to do that. Also at this stage it is not really a programming related question, more a DNS one.

Comment: "in the key "txt" there is a starange value" : there are no strange values there. TXT is an unstructured record, its data can be anything. Some specifications (SPF for example) piggyback on it and provide a format, but other than that you can find anything. And any name in the DNS can have multiple TXT records, why is that a problem for your case? To get SPF records specifically just filter out TXT records keeping only those starting with `v=spf1` And use `DNS_TXT` instead of `DNS_ANY`.

Comment: I have discovered that problem exist only for those spicific domain and if I querry from my local ip...is I querry from other ip it works just fine...is it possible that dns reject my request on the basis of my local ip?

Comment: What problem? You are not clear. The fact that a name has multiple TXT records is not a problem, this is normal. If you just want SPF related information, parse all TXT records and keep the one starting with `v=spf1`. And you can get different results depending from where and when you query, but in its current form your question is far too broad, and also do not seem at this point to be really programming related, so [su] may be a better forum for you.

Comment: I have found the real problem is that from my local ip (Ukraine) dns_get_record ('airhelp.com', DNS_ANY|DNS_TXT) returns false, while with some other params it works fine ( DNS_SOA|DNS_NS) ...I think it is some dns policy may be...I am interested how to get the reason of failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the real problem is that from my local ip (Ukraine) dns_get_record ('airhelp.com', DNS_ANY|DNS_TXT) returns false, while with some other params it works fine ( DNS_SOA|DNS_NS) ...I think it is some dns policy may be...I am interested how to get the reason of failure. –